# Google Compute Engine Cannot SSH using Owner Account

Tags: google-compute-engine

Since Google Compute Engine does not allow root user nor assign any password to the default Owner Account.

I though the SSH console in the Compute Engine backend can SSH to the instance regardless the SSH Config.

Obviously I was wrong, I modified sshd_config file and did not put the default owner account in the allowUsers parameter. Right now, I cannot SSH to the instance using owner account thus lost any SUDOER right and was stuck.

I however have set up a normal user which has no SUDOER rights but can SSH to the instance.

Is there any way to solve this or I have to rebuild the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can get around by attaching the boot disk of the instance in question as a data disk to another instance and editing sshd_config file.